# How to make SDL_Keypress detect new Keypress during keypress-loop?

Tags: c, sdl, keypress

I'm writing Conways game of life in C with SDL. The game logic and everything works fine but I want to have it when you press <kbd>p</kbd> for example that the game automatically updates until <kbd>p</kbd> is pressed again and the loop stops. Somehow it only repeats once and doesn't even register the second time <kbd>p</kbd> is pressed.

```
else if (e.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_p){
    bool stop = false;
    while (!stop){
        nextEpoch();
        updateGame(window, renderer, r);
        msleep(500);
        if (e.type == SDL_KEYDOWN){
            if (e.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_p){
                stop = true;
                printf("s\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't register that <kbd>p</kbd> is pressed when it in the while-loop.
Here's the full code: https://gist.github.com/PhilippRados/2df8760cc55822c2eac62addafb24403

Comment: Event structure is only updated when you call `SDL_PollEvent`. If you really want to, call that in inner loop.

Comment: @keltar Now it does register but it still only loops through twice and stops without me having pressed again

Comment: Can't guess, need to see the code.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel yeah I came to the conclusion that it would be more user-friendly to have an start button-image which can be pressed to start and stop the playing loop

Comment: @AndreasWenzel if you need to update unconditionally then SDL_WaitEvent would block and no update would happen.

Comment: @keltar: That is why in my answer, I have created a timer that creates an `SDL_USEREVENT` event at the desired frame rate. Unless the game is paused, this event triggers an update of the game state and rerenders it.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel haven't realized it updates at 2fps; that's probably best approach then. I'd be worried about frame pacing if update interval were supposed to be considerably high.

Answer (score 2):

As already pointed out by someone else in the comments section, you are not updating `e` in the inner loop. If you want to update `e` with a new event, you must call `SDL_PollEvent( &e )` again to fill it with a new event.

In your linked code, you seem to be attempting to implement a new state of your program outside the main event loop, which represents the running state of the program, whereas the main event loop represents the paused state of the program. That way, you effectively have two separate event loops, one for each state of the program. While it is possible to make your program work this way, I don't recommend it.

For example, the way you have designed your program, your program won't respond to `SDL_QUIT` events in the running state. It will only do so in the paused state.

Therefore, it would make more sense to have a single event loop for both the running and the paused states of your program.

I don't recommend that you call `usleep` or `SDL_Delay` for waiting until it is time to render the next frame, as your program will not be responding to user input during this time. Especially since you have a very low frame rate of 2 frames per second, this means that it will take up to half a second for your program to respond to user input (for example if the user resizes the window or attempts to close it). Instead, I recommend that you set up a timer using [`SDL_AddTimer`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_AddTimer). You can program the timer callback function to give you a `SDL_USEREVENT` event twice per second. That way, when you receive this event, you will know that it is time to update the game and render the next frame. While waiting for this event, your program will still be able to respond to other events.

Note that in order to use SDL timers, you must initialize the corresponding subsystem using the `SDL_INIT_TIMER` flag when calling [`SDL_Init`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Init). Strangely, your linked code does not seem to call `SDL_Init` at all, so I am surprised that your code works at all. According to the documentation, you should call `SDL_Init` like this:

`SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_TIMER | SDL_INIT_VIDEO );`

Also, calling [`SDL_PollEvent`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PollEvent) in a loop seems like a big waste of CPU resources, as your CPU usage will likely be 100% although you are effectively doing nothing most of the time. I recommend that you call [`SDL_WaitEvent`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_WaitEvent) instead, so that the thread will sleep until it receives a new event to respond to.

Another thing worth noting is that when handling an `SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` event, it does not seem appropriate to use the result of [`SDL_GetMouseState`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetMouseState) to determine the coordinates of the mouse click, as that function will return the current mouse coordinates and not the coordinates at the time of the click. Therefore, it would be more appropriate to read these coordinates from the [`SDL_MouseButtonEvent`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_MouseButtonEvent) structure.

Here is an example of how you could rewrite your event loop to use `SDL_WaitEvent` instead of `SDL_PollEvent` and to support both a running and a paused state in the main event loop.

```
Uint32 my_callbackfunc( Uint32 interval, void *param )
{
    SDL_Event e;

    e.user.type = SDL_USEREVENT;
    e.user.code = 0;
    e.user.data1 = NULL;
    e.user.data2 = NULL;

    SDL_PushEvent( &e );

    return interval;
}

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    [...]

    //set timer to trigger twice per second
    SDL_TimerID timer = SDL_AddTimer( 500, my_callbackfunc, NULL );
    if ( timer == 0 ) {
        //TODO: handle error
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    //start game in a paused state
    bool paused = true;

    while ( SDL_WaitEvent( &e ) ) {
        switch ( e.type ) {
        case SDL_QUIT:
            goto quit_game;
        case SDL_WINDOWEVENT:
            //rerender in case of window state change
            updateGame( window, renderer, r );
            break;
        case SDL_USEREVENT:
            if ( !paused ) {
                nextEpoch();
                updateGame(window, renderer, r);
            }
            break;
        case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mouseX = getNearestMultiple( e.button.x ) / RECT_SIZE;
            mouseY = getNearestMultiple( e.button.y) / RECT_SIZE;
            if ( Field[mouseX][mouseY] ) {
                //Deactivate cell
                Field[mouseX][mouseY] = false;
                updateGame(window,renderer,r);
            }
            else {
                //activate cell at position x,y
                Field[mouseX][mouseY] = true;
                updateGame(window,renderer,r);
            }
            break;
        case SDL_KEYDOWN:
            switch ( e.key.keysym.sym ) {
            case SDLK_SPACE:
                if ( paused ) {
                    nextEpoch();
                    updateGame(window, renderer, r);
                }
                break;
            case SDLK_r:
                memset(Field,0,sizeof(Field[0][0]) * WIDTH * HEIGHT);
                memset(nextState,0,sizeof(nextState[0][0]) * WIDTH * HEIGHT);
                updateGame(window,renderer, r);
                break;
            case SDLK_p:
                paused = !paused;
            }
        }
    }

quit_game:
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer I will try to implement the states as you have and I didn't know you could just do `e.button.x` to get the mouse coordinates which is pretty convenient... Schönes Wochenende noch

Comment: @Phil: Note that I have made the code in such a way that you only have to copy&paste it into your function `main`, and your code will work (I have tested it). Just replace the line `while (!quit){` and everything underneath with my code. You must also add my function `my_callbackfunc` to your code. I also highly recommend that you add a call to `SDL_Init` before calling any SDL functions, as the documentation clearly states that you must do this (otherwise you may be asking for trouble). See my answer for the function arguments you should use in this function call.

Comment: One more question: Instead of using a the keypress "p" to register a state change I instead used a button but this shouldn't make that big of a difference, however the game now gets stuck in the `SDL_WaitEvent` when I try to change to `!paused`. When I use `SDL_PollEvent` the window immediately collapses. Do you know what's going on here? This is the new code: https://gist.github.com/PhilippRados/999054fc864d9068b50e82a1cf614326

Comment: @Phil: There is no point in handling `SDL_USEREVENT` if you are not generating these events. Note that in my code, I am generating this event in the timer callback function, so that this event occurs twice per second. You did not take over my code which sets up this timer.

Comment: Ah ok I thought that since the timer wasn't called in the loop that it had no effect on the switch statements

Comment: @Phil: The `SDL_USEREVENT` event will not be generated by the system. It can only be generated by your own program. In my code, I use [`SDL_AddTimer`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_AddTimer) to set up a timer callback function, which generates this event in intervals of 500ms, so that your program knows when it is time to update the game state and render the next frame.

Comment: @Phil: If you want to use `msleep` instead of a timer, then you must change your event loop to use `SDL_PollEvent` instead of `SDL_WaitEvent` and move the `SDL_USEREVENT` handler code so that it is executed when `SDL_PollEvent` returns `0`. However, as already stated in my answer, this has the disadvantage that your program won't respond to user input while waiting with `msleep`. Therefore, I recommend using a timer.